# Hybrid IOS app not working in xcode simulator

Tags: xcode, selenium, automation, testng, appium-ios

I am using Xcode simulator to run testNG test. The code is written using Appium and Selenium. I observed that the IOS ipa file is getting installed  successfully using automation code but it's always in launching state and I am unable to perform any action on that (like click or type).

**Note:** When the ipa file is getting installed, a webdriver agent is also installed which I am not aware of what it is.

**Details:**

- Using Xcode simulator on Mac OS
- Appium : 12+
- simulator : all (ios 12, 13 , 6s)
- IOS app (hybrid)

The following code sets the desired capabilities for app execution:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities().iphone();
public void AppiumTestAppIOSSimulator(String appLoc, String deviceName, String udid, String portNumber) throws IOException {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + portNumber + "/wd/hub");
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.1");
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.0");
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.15.0");
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
            capabilities1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
            capabilities1.setCapability("app", appLoc);
            switchToWebViewIOS();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.info("Remote driver exception " + e);
        }
    }

public void switchToWebViewIOS() {
        driver = new IOSDriver(url, capabilities1);
        Set<String> availableContexts = ((AppiumDriver<WebElement>) driver).getContextHandles();
        log.info("Total No of Context Found After we reach to WebView = " + availableContexts.size());
        for (String context : availableContexts) {
            if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                webContext = context;
                log.info("Context Name is " + context);
                ((AppiumDriver) driver).context(context);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I run my test in mac OS simulator? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!